# Remove spacing before tab in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, whitespace

I want to get rid of the red marked spacing in the following demonstration:

> [image: Picture of problem without editing (original screenshot)] [image]

Word is placing a small amount of spacing before a tab I place at the start of a line. While this may not be very noticeable on large paper sizes (e.g. A4), it is definitely noticeable on small ones like A6 as demonstrated below.

> [image: Demonstration of problem on A6 paper]

Comment: I wouldn't be asking if I didn't want to use the tab. I want to create a space for somebody to place their signature.

Comment: You don't **need** <tabs> at the **start** of a line ...

Comment: What else would you suggest to create a signing line? Lots of underscores?

Comment: [I'm designing a form that needs to have “fill-in-the-blanks” lines. What is the best way to create them?](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/LinesInForms.htm) shows 5 different solutions you can choose from ...

Comment: Thank you, that solves the X of my XY problem. The question may still be interesting to solve anyways though so I'm not going to delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a tab for making a signature line, I used a table:

[image: Solution demo]

This is how to do it:

1. Create a 2x2 table.

   [image: A 2x2 table.]
2. Select the whole table and select **Design** → **Borders** → **No Border**.

   [image: How to select "No Border".]
3. Place your cursor in the upper left cell and select **Design** → **Borders** → **Bottom Border**.

   [image: How to select "Bottom Border".]
4. Place the text you want to be displayed into the cell below.
5. Select **Layout** → The dialog box launcher on **Cell Size** → **Options**. Enter `0` into the **Left** spinner.

   [image: Removing the left spacing in the table.]
6. Close all dialogs by pressing **OK** twice.
7. You can now write below this table. To add spacing below the table, place your cursor in the paragraph after the table and select **Home** → **Line and Paragraph Spacing** → **Add Space Before Paragraph**.

   [image: Adding spacing to a paragraph after a table]

---

Sources and references:

- [I'm designing a form that needs to have "fill-in-the-blanks" lines. What is the best way to create them?](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/LinesInForms.htm)